# Slow Group By at JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. I couldn't disclose anything about them so I mock up their structure:

**person** (at least 9000 records):

```
+---------------+-------------+
| Column        | type        | 
+---------------+-------------+
| person_id     | int(11)     | Primary Key
| name          | varchar(255)| 
| company_id    | int(10)     | 
+-----+---------+-------------+
```

**login** (more than 1000000 records):

```
+---------------+-------------+
| Column        | type        | 
+---------------+-------------+
| id            | int(11)     | Primary Key
| person_id     | int(11)     | 
| date          | datetime    | 
+-----+---------+-------------+
```

Every login is a record in the login table.
I have to list people from different companies (all people in given company at the time) with their latest login.

My query so far:

```
SELECT a.name, b.date 
FROM person a JOIN login b ON a.person_id = b.person_id 
WHERE company_id = ? 
GROUP BY b.person_id 
ORDER BY b.date DESC
```

This takes 4 to 11 seconds depending on the company and that seems very slow. As in one company there could be hundreds of people that logs in thousands of times, the login table is could be very big.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `max(b.date)`?

Comment: Pls provide the result of the explain and list the indexes on the relevant tables and the fields they contain for a start.

Comment: @Utsav max b.date gives me the same speed.

Comment: I wasn't mentioning about speed. Without `max(speed)` your query should have failed.

Comment: Try adding an index at you `person` table for your `company_id` field. This should optimize your query.

Comment: @FilipeMartins company_id in the person table is the primary key, therefore it is indexed by default. Adding an index to the same field in the login table would make more sense - if it is not there already.

Comment: As I do not built the database I didn't notice it has not indexes or anything in place. So yeah. I made index from company_id also fixed other tables. Now it is under 1 second for smaller companies and under 2 for the biggest ones. Thanks @FilipeMartins

Comment: I'd suggest adding a 'last_login_date' to the 'person' table and always have the latest login timestamp there. That way the login table can be more of a logtable and won't need to be queried all the time.

Comment: @ÁkosNikházy Glad to help.

Comment: Your SQL is wrong... https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank you this helped too! There is so much data it was hard to notice if something is wrong at this point, but I managed to get the actual query right after the blog reading.